# Access kubernetes docker for desktop from jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes

I've already installed a kubernetes docker for desktop and it's working fine. Then, I installed and configured a jenkins container.
Now, I want to deploy from jenkins container to kubernetes.
I installed Kubernetes Continuous Deploy Plugin and I configured the credential using the result of "`kubectl config view`" command

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://localhost:6445
  name: docker-for-desktop-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: docker-for-desktop-cluster
    user: docker-for-desktop
  name: docker-for-desktop
current-context: docker-for-desktop
kind: Config
preferences: {}
```

When I try to deploy to kubernetes from jenkins, I get this error

```
ERROR: ERROR: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Deployment]  with name: [sudoku]  in namespace: [default]  failed.
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Deployment]  with name: [sudoku]  in namespace: [default]  failed.
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:62)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:71)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:206)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:162)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientWrapper$DeploymentUpdater.getCurrentResource(KubernetesClientWrapper.java:404)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientWrapper$DeploymentUpdater.getCurrentResource(KubernetesClientWrapper.java:392)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientWrapper$ResourceUpdater.createOrApply(KubernetesClientWrapper.java:358)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesClientWrapper.apply(KubernetesClientWrapper.java:157)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.doCall(DeploymentCommand.java:168)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.call(DeploymentCommand.java:122)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand$DeploymentTask.call(DeploymentCommand.java:105)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1165)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand.execute(DeploymentCommand.java:67)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.command.DeploymentCommand.execute(DeploymentCommand.java:46)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.runCommand(CommandService.java:88)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.execute(CommandService.java:96)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.executeCommands(CommandService.java:75)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.BaseCommandContext.executeCommands(BaseCommandContext.java:77)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.kubernetes.KubernetesDeploy.perform(KubernetesDeploy.java:42)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.build(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:945)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:896)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1810)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /localhost:6445
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:240)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:158)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:54)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils$2.intercept(HttpClientUtils.java:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:379)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:344)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:313)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:296)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:770)
    at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:195)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at okhttp3.internal.platform.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:125)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:238)
    ... 55 more
```

Obviusly the error is the address of kubernetes but I don't know how to retrieve the correct one.
I tried the one I can see in kubernetes under the `Service > Kubernetes > Deploy` but it doen't work. Where can I find the correct one?

Comment: what services run in your cluster?

Comment: at the moment I only have this
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   1d

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lays in kubeconfig file, to be precise in following section:

> server: https://localhost:6445

It`s of course valid in context of your local machine, but not when you are trying to use it to reach Kubernetes cluster from inside of node/agent jenkins container. Containers are having unique hostname, so talking from container to https://localhost address is like talking to itself.

**Solution:**

please replace 'localhost' with either 'host.docker.internal', 'docker.for.win.localhost' (if you are on Windows) or simply local IP address of your local machine, like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://docker.for.win.localhost:6445
  name: docker-for-desktop-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: docker-for-desktop-cluster
    user: docker-for-desktop
  name: docker-for-desktop
current-context: docker-for-desktop
...
```

You can read more on Docker Desktop networking [here](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/)